# How to add block to only user/uid and not user/uid/edit

Tags: navigation

In my site the www.example/user/uid path contains the view and edit tabs. I want to add some blocks to only the view page and not edit page.

Using "user/* (Only the listed pages)" under the visibility settings of block configuration attaches the block to both pages.

How can I make it appear on only the view page.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7,

- You can achive it by enabling **PHP filter** module, which allows embedded PHP code/snippets to be evaluated. GO to **admin > modules** and enable **PHP filter**.

  `<?php
      global $user;
      if (arg(0) == 'user' && $user->uid == arg(1) && is_numeric(arg(1)) && (arg(2) == NULL) ){
        return TRUE;
      }
      else {
        return FALSE;
      }
  ?>`

  [image]
- You can also refer [**Extended block visibility**](https://drupal.org/project/extended_block_visibility) module. This will allows PHP block visibility to be defined in code.

Comment: Thanks, but please i do not understand this code or how to apply it.

Comment: When user is viewing the his profile, then the arguments will be user and user ID. So Im checking arg(0) == 'user' and arg(1) must be numeric. If it is the user edit page, then arg(2) will be not NULL. So I'm checking for all the 3 conditions.

Comment: Enjoy coding :)

Comment: But this method requires that you enable the PHP Filter module which I never do. (Side note: In D6 you didn't need to enable the PHP Filter module to use PHP for block visibility - I'd be interested in a link to the issue that changed this if anyone can find it). Anyway, IMHO this logic should be moved to a module because the PHP Filter module is a deal-breaker.

Answer (score 1):

you could write some php in the visibility settings checking the path like:

```
<?php
 $path = explode('/', $_GET['q']);
 if ($path[0] == 'user') {
   if (is_numeric($path[1]) && $path[2] != 'edit') {
     return TRUE;
   }
 }
```

...something like that (untested).
This could be handled in a user_view hook also, but this the simple solution.

Be carefull what PHP you write in there because if it breaks the site you will have to remove this code form block's records in the database!

Comment: Thanks. The code by @inizio works fine when added to the visibility settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would enable Panels and Page Manager and under Pages enable the user_view variant. Then place the block in where you want it in the layout.

You will also need to place normal "user" elements in the layout to not suddenly display nothing :)